# Not able to set the width of alert box

Tags: sencha-touch

[image]I have this simple alert box that shows a simple message but when the text is too long then it gets cut off.. Is there any way that I can set the width of the alert box..

I tried Ext.Msg.MinWidth=300;

But that didn't work

```
onForgotPwdTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {        
        Ext.Msg.alert('Forgot Password?', 'Please contact your administrator for password assistance.', Ext.emptyFn);
    }
```

Comment: Probably you have done some changes in sencha alert box css. I tried your code but can not duplicate the issue. It is coming like https://www.dropbox.com/s/1i91hlogwq3ax2k/Screenshot%20from%202014-03-24%2012%3A36%3A30.png

Comment: @AnandGupta No i did not, after your reply i tried it on Chrome and safari and it works fine. So this is happening only on IE-10. So even for that I will have to change the width accordingly. So is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the screen dimensions like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int mwidth = display.getWidth();
int mheight = display.getHeight();
And then alter the Dialog like this:

AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
// (That new View is just there to have something inside the dialog that can grow big enough to cover the whole screen.)

d.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = mwidth;
lp.height = myheight;

//change position of window on screen
lp.x = mwidth/2; //set these values to what work for you; probably like I have here at
lp.y = mheight/2;        //half the screen width and height so it is in center

//set the dim level of the background
lp.dimAmount=0.1f; //change this value for more or less dimming

d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

//add a blur/dim flags
d.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: I appreciate your code, but this is not what I am looking for. This is a workaround not a solution to my issue. But anyways thanks for trying.